# Believe it or not, a css issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, cross-browser, z-index

I have a menu that is dropping behind other elements - I have tried z-indexing on what I thought were the relevent parts, but to no avail -

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to **make this dropdown be on top of other elements** in IExplorer? Looks fine in FF, Chrome, Safari - thank you for your help

Beta testing site: http://bit.ly/Hb0RJz

Comment: Link trying to redirect.  Please adjust it.

Comment: @Fallenreaper - Looks like it redirects to https://beta.keepsakequilting.com/checkout/shoppingbag1021test.aspx . I got an expected SSL warning because the cert isn't explicitly for their `beta` subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with the **stacking context** of the elements. Since the two elements have different stacking contexts, z-index won't work. Take a look at [this page](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/).

Also answered here: [IE7 dropdown menu appears behind image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790305/ie7-dropdown-menu-appears-behind-image) and [CSS Dropdown menu hidden behind content IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581160/css-dropdown-menu-hidden-behind-content-ie7)

Comment: Thank you very much -- I got it to work with your suggestion and now it drops over the other elements in IE, but I ended up with an issue I had prior to this (in all browsers) and had been fixed until I made this change. The sub menu is under the first menu now. If you look at this jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/keltoid/UPSba/ under Quilt Fabrics, the second level submenu is going UNDER the first again.. I've tried everything. Your fix of putting z-index:1 in Line 29 worked, as far as stack order in IE, but now you can see the sub menu is going under it.Can you see the issue?

Comment: Anyway.  I'm pretty ticked off I had a halfway decent menu and have to screw it all up for internet explorer. Its the 21st century, I can't believe we still have to deal with this %$#@.
I can't get it right now.  I have tried EVERYTHING.  Is there anyone who can help me?  I've edited the jsfiddle -- and now its not what it was.  So... I'm so sick of trying things that don't work.

Comment: @Promo Hey! I know what you mean. I was just answering you. I see the issue. I had a stab at it but couldn't quite manage to solve it. I think it has to do with the natural stacking order of the elements (as they appear in the DOM). If you find a way to modify the z-index of the `.column` elements to a value lower than the `.menu-container` being shown, you should be on the right track. But couldn't get any further than that. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks hqcasanova - I appreciate the attempt -- I'll check it out again and see if I can get through all the stacking going on.  :)