# IE/: wrong z-index for hover-effect

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

i build an hover-effect using CSS only. It works fine in all browsers except IE7.

**[Visit the page](http://www.tanz-scherg-pfaffenhofen.de/das-tanzstudio/tanzlehrer/)** or **[view a screenshot](http://p8472.typo3server.info/stackoverflow/z-index-ie7/ie7.gif)**.

As i read, it's because:

> In Internet Explorer versions 6 and 7, the stacking order of z-indexed elements is essentially “reset” for any elements that are contained by a positioned element, regardless of wether or not the container (or parent) has a z-index value set. In other words, an element with a z-index value of 100 will appear underneath an element with a z-index value of 1 if the former element is contained by a positioned parent, and the latter is not. This is an incorrrect implementation of the z-index property that has evidently been corrected in IE8.

But how can i fix this IE7-bug?

Comment: Deleted the experiment fixing the bug with jQuery! There must be a solution only based on CSS, because i rebuilt the whole markup in JSFiddle and in works in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/WK93H/2/ Therefore we have to search the bug within the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want "z-index" instead of "zIndex."  I've never seen or used the "zIndex" string.  However, I am not sure if this will fix your problem.

Comment: The jQuery code seems to work. When using my debugger i can see the correct CSS put into the HTML code with jQuery ([Watch the screenshot](http://p8472.typo3server.info/stackoverflow/z-index-ie7/jQuery-ok.png)).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:relative;` to your style. z-index bug for ie7 is pretty popular. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem) that explains more about it.

Comment: All my elements unsing the `z-index` are already set so a specific `position` ([watch the css](http://www.tanz-scherg-pfaffenhofen.de/fileadmin/css/screen.css)): 

`.tanzlehrer-wrap { position: relative; }` and `.tanzlehrer-wrap .tanzlehrer { position: absolute; }`

Comment: Amir, my problem i a bit more complex than explained in your link. When using two nested elements both using `z-index` and `position`, IE7 displays the inner element wrong.