# div layering problems

Tags: html, css

I am developing for an existing web application on an internal server, I can't really post all the code here as it's very very messy but I can show you guys a screenshot of the problem and the relevant css code:

[image]

The languages menu should be on top of the blue bordered box, but instead it's beneath.

**It works great in FF, this is a IE7 screenshot**

blue bordered box css:

```
.categoryBox {
    width:100px;
    background-color:#000;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#007CF7;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    height:260px;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
}
```

language menu css:

```
#ChooseLanguageDlg
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;     
    width: 87px; 
    height: 180px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top:0;
    margin-top: -9px;
    border: none 1px White;
    left: 751px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size:11px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Note: the languages menu is using a javascript toggle to show/hide.

**EDIT:**
Adding z-index to the language box does not change the visibility in IE

Comment: check if any of the parent node of languages box is behind the category box or not

Comment: You could make a test case on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) by taking the source of the problematic page and placing imported stylesheets in `<style>` tags. You could also redact any text on the page, if you like. So long as the demo also has the IE7 problem, I should be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 has known problems with `z-index`. Without seeing your page, the best I can do is point you to some useful links which explain the problem:

- http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/
- [IE7 Z-Index Layering Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem)
- http://richa.avasthi.name/blogs/tepumpkin/2008/01/11/ie7-lessons-learned/

The general idea is to poke `position: relative` (usually remove it) and `z-index` on parent elements of your drop down until it's fixed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `z-index` of the language box manually may help. Of course, if you don't want to do this, putting the language box after the blue box in the markup will do the trick too.

Comment: i've tried adding ``z-index:999`` to the language box, but it doesn't change anything. Also, moving the language box to another location is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a z-index. This'll define which element is on top of which element:
[z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

add a z-index to the style for the language box?

Answer (score 0):

IE has some problem with z-index (see Google). As I had to fix a similar problem I was forced to use javascript to hide the background elements, which isn't really suitable for you.

You could try to change the order of creation in the html code, if possible.