# Why is my CSS drop-down menu opening behind a DIV in IE7?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

This issue has been stumping me.

This only happens in IE7. I saw some similar subjects, and tried the solutions, but couldn't get them to work.

Any ideas?

http://signhit.com/

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [div layering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154168/div-layering-problems/5154440#5154440)

> The general idea is to poke `position:
>   relative` (usually remove it) and
>   `z-index` on parent elements of your
>   drop down until it's fixed.

I wasn't kidding about `position: relative`.

You've obviously already read up on the problem you're experiencing and tried out the solutions; I can see `z-index` scattered around on various elements.

There's *one more step* to fix the dropdown to work in IE7:

- From `#content`, remove `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#nav_main ul
{
  overflow: auto;
}

#nav_main ul li
{
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Another problem could be that the Flash video is doing it, but since I don't use Flash, I can't help much.