# Annoying IE6 bug

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-6, z-index

Read about the z-index issue and tried anything, but just can't seem to fix this.

Please check this in IE6: http://bit.ly/ld54WO

I'd really appreciate any help.

Many thanks

Comment: does microsoft even support this anymore?

Comment: did you try this solution ? http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: @Woot4Moo Right, but popular websites still do, can't afford to lose even 5% of the customers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to simply remove `position: relative` from your "NOT OK" `div`.

But, I'm guessing that for whatever reason, that's not an option for you.

So, another fix is to remove `position: relative` from `<header class="cl">`.

I've tested this with your actual page using genuine IE6.

For more info, see: [div layering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154168/div-layering-problems/5154440#5154440)

Answer (score 1):

See tab 4 @ http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Maybe that will help achieve it for you.

Comment: oops, yeah realized I was thinking his problem was something else

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue might be that you are using HTML5 (from HTML5 Boilerplate, http://html5boilerplate.com/), which is not supported by IE6. My guess is that if you change all your invalid elements (nav, header) to valid XHTML or HTML4, the issue will resolve itself.

Comment: This is not relevant to the problem - changing `nav`/`header` to `div` won't make one iota of difference. HTML5 Boilerplate includes Modernizr, which adds support for the HTML5 elements in older versions of IE.

Comment: Modernizr helps IE6 recognize those elements, but the browser still doesn't put the expected default styling on them, rendering many of them as inline.

Comment: True, but HTML5 Boilerplate's CSS includes `article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
`.

Comment: Accurate; that's assuming all the necessary files are being used. I'm merely cautioning to proceed with care using these elements in IE6. Even with boilerplate there are still some complexities.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is minimizing floating & positioning/z-indexing. Question, why do you need to have the red container to be relative?

I took the initiative in a menu with minimal style(no z-index used too):

http://jsfiddle.net/CbNr4/1/

I recommend not making the site look "exactly" the same as for IE6. you will go insane.

Hope this make sense