# Div Hidden behind another DIV with Web User Control in it

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I am having some problems with my DIV, it wont display over a a DIV that has a web user control in it. Below you can find my css. I believe I have done everything right and am hoping that someone can maybe see an error that I have made and help me out. If you need any other code let me know. I also wonder if its just IE rendering it wrong? Thanks for looking.

[image]

The Popup CSS:

```
{
    background: #ececec; 
    position:absolute; 
    top: 236px; 
    left: 201px; 
    height: auto; 
    width: 280px; 
    border: solid 1px gray; 
    z-index: 50; 
    text-align:left; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    padding-top: 5px; 
    padding-bottom: 15px; 
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

The Activity DIV (same the div above just changed position)

```
{
    border: solid 2px #A9C5EB;
    position: absolute;
    top: 353px;
    left: 290px;
    width: 710px;
    height: 227px;
    font-size: small;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #F8FBFE;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: You're using IE 7 :)  Sorry, I had to.  What's your doc type (in quirks mode)?

Comment: @DanAndrews -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the HTML is essential to fix your problem.

What is the html that contains your popup? Is it relative to the body tag or some other element? Is the containing element `position: relative;`?

Try setting the containing element's z-index and position:

```
#my-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem) about absolute positioning.

On a side note, check out [IE-7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) which fixes many IE browser issues, including - AFAIK - this bug.

Comment: Well theres part of what I think may be causing the problem. That whole left panel including the popup is in an ascx file. So when it renders the page, it puts all that together. Yet for some reason it doesnt see it as being in the same stack element.

Comment: Without really seeing the complete page source, it's very difficult to debug.  We could shoot in the dark to find an answer, but may be modded down for being wrong.