# Yet another IE7 Z-Index Issue (in table cells)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I know there's a lot of questions about ie7 z-index issues, 
I took a look at theses and none of them seems to solve my problem so here's yet another IE7 z-index question:

I have a table with cells containing long texts,
I'd like to show the full text when hovering a cell, in a pure CSS way (I'd really like to avoid another js fix because the app is already pretty slow client side with IE7 because of big tables).

I got it working on FF/Chrome/IE8/IE9 with that method:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zppy4/15/
but I can't get it to work with IE7.

If someone have a magic idea, any help is welcome :)

thanks in advance

Comment: you coulf try here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem     I would like to try it myself but I don't have internet explorer in linux.

Comment: It's really a bad idea to use `display: none` on the "extra" content there. What about users who navigate by keyboard? Touch device users?

Comment: @steveax: it's a web app, we only need IE7+ and FF to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing `.c { position: relative }` and adding `.c:hover { position: relative }`. Not tested but think this should work

here is another: add `.c { z-index: 10000 }` and `.c:hover { z-index: 10001 }`