# Internet Explorer Z-Index

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hover, z-index

I've wrote a tiny JavaScript for this side: http://www.tx-customers.com/ep-immobilien/?page_id=183.

Now in the Internet Explorer I get problems with the layers, so the Hover functions doesn't work correctly. There're list items on top of the Images relating to a specific images, changing the class of this image to be viewed. This works but if you click one Image or the Slider activates (after 3 Seconds) the li-items are lying behind the shown image. It works in FF, Opera, Safari and Chrome.
I've searched for z-index Workarounds tried to set the positions and z-indexes but it changed nothing.

The HTML Structure is:

```
<div id="team">
    <div class="images">
        <img id="1-team-member-picture" class="team-member" src="img-src" rel="185">
        <li class="splitter" rel="1"></li>
        <img id="2-team-member-picture" class="team-member" src="img-src" rel="185">
        <li class="splitter" rel="2"></li>
        <div id="results">
            <p class="res"></p>
        </div>
        <p class="clear"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS Code:

```
#team .images {
    float: left;
    background: url(images/gesamt_962px.png) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    height: 382px;
    width: 769px;
    z-index: 5;
    padding-left: 64px;
}

#team .images img {
    height: 382px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}

#team .images .team-member {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 32px;
}

#team .images .current, #team .images .clicked {
    display: inline;
}

#team .images li {
    width: 30px;
    height: 382px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

CSS Code for IE ( a try) :

```
#mainwrap {
    font: 14px/20px Times New Roman, Times, sans-serif;
}

#team {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}

#team .images {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/gesamt_962px.png) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    height: 382px;
    width: 769px;
    padding-left: 64px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#team .images .team-member {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 32px;
    z-index: 0 !important;
}

#team .images .current, #team .images .clicked {
    position: absolue;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 0 !important;
}

#team .images li {
    width: 30px;
    height: 382px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

And this is the Script:
http://www.tx-customers.com/ep-immobilien/wp-content/themes/epi/js/teamSlider.js

It's my first try in JS, so please don't blame me for some stupid coding! :P

A part of the JS where the Hover is used.

```
jQuery($splitter).mouseover( function () {
    if(!$clicked) stopAnimate();
    slideRemoveClass("current");
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '-team-member-picture').addClass("current");
});

jQuery($splitter).mouseleave( function () {
    if(!$clicked) animate();
    slideRemoveClass("current");
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '-team-member-picture').removeClass("current");
});

function animate() {
    clearTimeout(interval);
    interval = setTimeout( slide, $delay );
}

function stopAnimate() {
    clearTimeout(interval);
}
```

Comment: Nothing works :/ the IE should not be used by anyone! Someone a idea?

Answer (score 1):

Z-Indexing is... strange, for lack of a more appropriate word, in IE.

To make a long story short, to properly use z-indexing with IE every element (from parent to child) involved has to have a z-index (sometimes all the way back to the body).

This question here did an excellent job of answering this:
[IE7 Z-Index Layering Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem)

Comment: I'll will isolate the code and test it with your suggestion and let you know of the result

Comment: Hm, thanks for your great answer but i cant solve this problem :/

Comment: Are you able to post your JS code, or at least the part that deals with the on hover?  

I once nearly tore my hair out thanks to IE doing a site that had an expanding menu that went over an image display that rotated (no flash involved, all HTML, CSS, and JavaScript) and ultimately this was the solution.  I think yours is the same, and I know you'll breath easier like I did when its finally solved!

Comment: I Updated my Question and added the JS Code ( there's also a link to the whole Script a bit higher)

Comment: Found the Problem: You have to set a background color in Internet Explorer. Here the fix: background-color: #fff; filter: alpha(opacity=1);