# Trouble with z-index in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I have a drop down menu on: http://whitehornguard.com/ but in at least IE7 the drop down part is appearing underneath the large header image, I have tried changing the z-index & using !important but it doesn't seem to be making any difference..

What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: A well-known problem. Google "ie7 z-index" for articles. Here's one that sounds a lot like your situation: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: possible duplicate of [ie7 z-index problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem)

Comment: make sure your #header_image and li.menu_item has a z-index as well

Comment: Just gave them all a z-index & position, still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with IE. There is a trick to workaround it.
Try wrapping the menu with additional container with the following styling:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative; z-index: 1000;">
    <div id="menu" style="position:absolute; z-index: 999;"></div>
</div>
```

Please notice that the menu's z-index is less then the container.

For more details please check: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: Thanks, I used a div I already had as a wrapper, but what made it work was giving children smaller indexes than their parents.

Comment: the child element's z-index cannot exceed their parent's z-index. Its specified in w3c standards

Comment: What is specified in w3c standards not respected by IE : )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that IE just requires some use of *position*. So the z.index will just be used, if *position* is present. For an element, you don't want to give any positioning-rules, just try to set *position:relative*

Comment: All nodes that I have used z-index on also have position set.

Answer (score 0):

You wrap your `nav` in a `div` with inline styles. Add `z-index:1000;` to it. It fixes the issue.