# DropDownCheckList in floated divs

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm using [DropDownCheckList for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) as replacement for the default select options, and in IE7 I'm having this problem:

[image: Original select box behind new div]

The 'original' select element appears behind the new added DIV onclick, this only happens in IE7 in floated divs and seems to be fine in any other browser..

Is there a fix for this, or do I have to convince people to finally drop IE7?

Comment: that may be about z-index and ie7 but not sure. Maybe you wanna check here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1287439/1241723