# Issue in IE7 probably z-index bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have added a drop down menu on link Recipes in the main navigation.

Test URL: http://jaspreetkaur.com/makebathsalts/

It's working fine in all browsers except IE7 (not tested in IE6)

Menu is going behind banner area in IE7, i think it's related to z-index bug of IE7. I found some details on following page, but not able to fix this.
[IE7 Z-Index Layering Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
#navigation{position:relative;z-index:10;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is simple, you need to specify the `z-index` for the direct parent of the ul menu, in your case the `li` with class `active` like this:

```
 li.active {
     position:relative;
     z-index:10;
 }
```