# Z-index issues in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, z-index

I have a login form in popup in header of my page and below it i have a navigation when i have open the popup the navigation links are showing above the popup. I have set the z-index of navigation 1 and z-index of popup is 10 but is not working in IE7. Anyone can help me

Comment: Try to read [this article][1]
Maybe it was helpful for you.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug of IE7. Doesnt work in IE7 and IE8(compatibility view). Work around for this is: You need to check the hierarchy. Both pop-up and should be in the same stacking context/or you can say must have parent child relationship. and keep the parent/popup as relative and the z-index should be greater than the child.

you can also check the following link from where i got its example

http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 0):

You ll need to set the popup position as relative, IE reads z-index only when its position is set to relative, just give it a try