# IE7 z-index layer bug

Tags: css, z-index, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE7 Z-Index Layering Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-layering-issues)

a bug on IE7 is driving me mad... the nav goes under a jquery cycle sliding panel on the homepage of this site:
http://www.marshall-trailers.co.uk/

i've followed the fixes for the known IE7 z-index bug, but it still doesn't work.  i've also been looking at another site i did recently http://www.dowdeswell.co.uk/  which does work!

the main css file is: www.marshall-trailers.co.uk/css/screen.css
the div to loo at are: nav_container, slider_wrapper, slider

its going to be something really simple i think... can someone please put me out of my misery?!

cheers,

rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move that 'z-index:100' property in the '.nav_container' rule to the '#header' rule.

The z-index's of elements in IE7 are only relative to their sibling elements in the code hierarchy ...if that makes sense ;)

Comment: unbelievable!  ...thanks for making the pain stop.