# IE7 Menu Behind Image z-index

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I cannot get the menu in front of the image, anybody has any clue?

http://goo.gl/jAVDv

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no context and no usefulness to future users. All the context is in a link to a site which has changed since then and does not reflect the issue reported in the question any longer. Question should contain the problem code, possibly in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave z-index:9999 to menu's one of main parent. When I gave high z-index to his great grandfather the problem solved.

Comment: Here is a good SO answer on what I think was your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-layering-issues