# Problems with dropdown and jquery-ui dialog box

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a page with `dropdown` list and `Dialog` component from the jQuery UI library.

But the issue is `dropdown` list appears over `dialog box` in IE7  .In chrome,Mozilla Firefox  it works fine.

Here is the code for jquery:-

```
var divdialog = $('#divdialog'); divdialog.dialog('destroy');
    divdialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 310,
        width: 570,title: "Look Up",
        modal: true,
        open: function () {$('#testframe').attr("src", strValue);
        $('#testframe').height($(this).height()-5); $('#testframe').width($(this).width()-10);         
            },
        close: function (e) {
            $('#divdialog').remove();
            //divdialog.html('');
           // divdialog.dialog('destroy');
            },
        resizable: true,
        resize: function() { $('#divdialog iframe').hide(); },
        resizeStop: function() { $('#divdialog iframe').show(); 
        $('#divdialog iframe').height($(this).height()-10);  
        $('#divdialog iframe').width($(this).width()-10); } ,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        draggable:true
    })
```

Here is the code for UI:-

```
        <div id="divdialog" style="display:none;">
             <iframe id="testframe" frameborder="0" title="dialogBox"><p>not supportted iframe</p></iframe>
    </div>

<asp:DropDownList  ID="ddlRoleNames" runat="server" Width="180px" 
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRoleNames_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

[image]

Any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That might be because of the Z-index, why because even if your element is having the z-index as 1000, there will be a chance of having that element below the element with z-index as 1, if the both are not in the same stacking contexts.

So try giving the position as absolute in dropdown and let me know .

have a look at the below question also which may help

[IE7 Z-Index Layering Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-layering-issues)

Hope this helps

Comment: `position:absolute;` now works for Firefox but still have same problem in IE7.

Comment: Post some of your code you tried then it will be simple to help.