# Stacking issue with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

When adding a dropdown to a table row, it is getting cut off as so:
[image]

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-layering-issues) have pointed me in the direction of a stacking problem, but I just can't work out how to fix it. I have tried adding `z-index:1000` and `position:relative` style attributes to each of the parent DIV's but that hasn't fixed the issue. Not sure what to try next...

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="grid simple ">
            <div class="grid-body table_highlight>
                <table class="table table-striped" id="example2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-demo-space" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Info <span class="caret"></span> </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I have changed the code to the following to make it clearer how it all fits together:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style=" border: 5px red solid;">
    <div class="span12" style=" border: 5px green solid;">
        <div class="grid simple " style=" border: 5px blue solid;">
            <div class="grid-title">
                ...
            </div>
                <div class="grid-body table_highlight" style=" border: 5px yellow solid;">
```

This is how it now appears:

[image]

Comment: Could you also post the html of the next element that blocks the dropdown?

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz I have edited the question to highlight the different DIV's. It seems to be the grid-body it is having an issue with, but I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Your code above looks ok in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/napple/bmFCY/ - Could you share more of your code to help illustrate where the probably is?

Comment: @NathanApple It's clearly something I've done wrong then. I have added my CSS page to: http://jsfiddle.net/PhALG/1/ and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that the grid-body class has an `overflow` style set to `hidden`. When the dropdown is activated, its size is larger than the grid-body's size, so the dropdown gets clipped. You can see it fixed if you add `overflow: visible` to the style attribute on your div with the grid-body class: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/napple/PhALG/2/)

As a permanent fix, you might want to explore modifying the HTML and/or CSS instead of just adding the style directly to the element, though.