# IE7 Chosen, dropdown over dropdown

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

guys could you please help me with this. I'm using chosen.js and have a problem with dropdowns, please see the picture [problem with dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWy9S.png)

This is the html code

```
<select id="SelectedInterval" class="chosen_select" name="SelectedInterval">
<option value="3m">3 months</option>
<option value="6m">6 months</option>
<option value="9m" selected="selected">9 months</option>
<option value="1y">1 year</option>
<option value="2y">2 years</option>
</select>
```

And I'm using standard chosen.css

Comment: Can you post the entire page's code. Missing important details, like which version of jquery.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.12, chosen Version 0.9.8. This problem occurs only in IE7 it works perfectly in FF or chrome

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to fix this thanks to: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-layering-issues)

The key think is that  "It is possible for an element with z-index: 1000 to be behind an element with z-index: 1 - as long as the respective elements belong to different stacking contexts."

So I put my dive to have bigger z index than the div below